# Terraform reusable variable block

Tags: terraform

I have two lambdas in my terraform configuration and I want them to have the exact same environment variables.

I'd like to not need to modify both lambda environment blocks every time I modify one. Is it possible to have some kind of a reusable block?

So instead of this:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "f1" {
   <..>
   environment {
    variables = {
      ENV_STAGE = "${lower(var.environment)}" # all of these will always be same for both lambdas
      A = "A"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "f2" {
  <..>
  environment {
    variables = {
      ENV_STAGE = "${lower(var.environment)}"
      A = "A"
    }
  }
}
```

It would be something like this:

```
env = {
    variables = {
      ENV_STAGE = "${lower(var.environment)}"
      A = "A"
    }
 }

resource "aws_lambda_function" "f1" {
  <..>
  environment = env
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "f2" {
  <..>
  environment = env
}
```

Comment: You could combine the two resources and iterate over them twice. Whether that is feasible or not depends upon the differences between the two lambda resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a [locals block](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html)

```
locals {
  shared_env_variables = {
    ENV_STAGE = "${lower(var.environment)}"
    A = "A"
  }
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "f1" {
  environment {
    variables = merge(local.shared_env_variables, {
       ONLY_FOR_F1: "something"
    })
  }
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "f2" {
  environment {
    variables = local.shared_env_variables
  }
}
```

More advanced things like creating resources based on a map are  possible with [`for_each`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#for_each-multiple-resource-instances-defined-by-a-map-or-set-of-strings)

Answer (score 2):

@dtech answer is correct, I just want to add that the syntax for v0.11 is slightly different (what I'm currently using).

[Source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/locals.html)

```
locals {
  common_env = {
    ENV_STAGE              = "${lower(var.environment)}"
  }
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "Lambda" {
  <..>
  environment {
    variables = "${merge(local.common_env)}"
  }
}
```